# With my code, how do i fetch data of some rows and column instead of every data on the sheet using php

Tags: php

I have a working code that retrieves every data in an excel sheet from the beginning to the end.. I would like my code to retrieve data beginning from a certain point and not just from the first line e.g i would love to loop through the data from row1 column 2 downwards instead of row1 column1. Right now, my code only retrieves Rows only, and no column. How do i specify column in the result, using my code. Thank you

```
<?php
require_once('db_config.php');
require_once('library/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('library/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{


  $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {

            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {

                $name = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$Row[0]);
                }

                $description = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$Row[1]);
                }

                if (!empty($name) || !empty($description)) {
                    $query = "insert into tbl_info(name,description) values('".$name."','".$description."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

                    if (! empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                    }
                }
             }

         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Invalid File Type. Upload Excel File.";
  }
}
?>
```

i expect to my code to loop from a certain point, let say second or third row, and not every data in a row

Comment: Without knowing anything about the excel reader class you are using, the code looks like you’re uploading a file, the the class reads each sheet in the excel file and each row from each sheet, you are then inserting the first 2 columns of each sheet (which appear to be a name - col 1 and description - col 2) into a MySQL database. If you want to skip over a few rows you can add an if statement with a continue to skip the insert based on the row number. Looks like you are already selecting certain columns to insert. Let me know if that’s what you’re trying the achieve?

Comment: Continue. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Exactly, skipping few rows is what am trying to achieve. Just the first line of data.

Comment: So just add a key to the foreach, ie $rows as $key => $row

Comment: Then add a if $key = 0, continue, to skip the first row